# How to check whether a line exists inside a circle or not?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a line equation in the form of **ax + by +c = 0**. And I have a circle with radius **r**. I want to know whether the line exists inside the circle or not??

Comment: Need to know the center of the circle also. Find the distance from the line to that center (there's a known simple formula) and see if that distance is less than $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the center of the circle be $(h,k)$. The formula for the distance from the line $ax+by+c=0$ to the center is then
$$d=\frac{|ah+bk+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
Thus your line will enter the interior of the circle if and only if the circle radius $r$ satisfies $r>d$, and the line will be tangent to the circle (and so hit it at one point) if and only if $r=d$. Finally when $r<d$ the line will have no points in common with the circle (or its interior).

The above distance formula has several proofs, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

Comment: Perhaps you could add on how to derive that formula.

Comment: @Sawarnik I saw no reason to type out a derivation, when it is a well known formula. I did insert a link to the Wiki page on this, which has several proofs of it using different approaches.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, add a link. Never mind :)

Comment: @Sawarnik I do appreciate your comment requesting a proof/link. It completes the answer so someone not knowing that formula can look up the details to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If the circle is centered at the origin, then for the line to be outside the circle, the following must have no solutions:
$$y = (-c - ax)/b,\quad y^2+x^2=R^2$$
Or:
$$(c+ax)^2/b^2+x^2=R^2\to x^2(a^2/b^2+1)=R^2-\frac{c}{b^2}$$
Thus, the condition for the line not crossing the circle:
$$R^2<c/b^2$$

Answer (score 0):

First, only a line *segment* can exist inside a circle.  An entire line is infinitely long.  You probably meant to ask whether a line intersects a circle.

You suppose the center of your circle is $(c_x, c_y)$.  The points of your circle satisfy:
$$(x-c_x)^2 + (y-c_y)^2 = r^2 \tag{C}$$

Your line is $$ax + by + c = 0 \tag{L}$$

You have two equations, (C) and (L), and two variables x and y.  Solve (L) for x or y and plug that into (C), you'll get a quadratic equation.

Sometimes a quadratic has two solutions, sometimes it has one solution, sometimes it has zero solutions.  Can you figure out how these three cases relate to line circle intersection?